# Struggling getting Boost library unit test framework to work

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, visual-studio-2013

I've successfully built the Boost libraries using VS2013. I've also successfully included and used some of Boost.Filesystem and Boost.Log stuff. However, I'm struggling to get the following unit test to work in Visual Studio 2013:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

class Multiplier {
public:
    explicit Multiplier(int i) : _value{ i } {}
    int multiply(int i) { return _value * i; }
private:
    int _value;
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(everything_test) {
    Multiplier m{ 5 };
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(m.multiply(2), 10);
}
```

This obviously isn't a real unit test, but that's not the point... :)

By including `boost/test/included/unit_text.hpp`, I should be getting a `main()` function supplied for me, and it appears I am since I was able to get that error resolved. When I run my resulting executable, though, I get an `Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

Am I supposed to run the executable to run the tests? If not, how do I run them? Running the tests seems like such a simple operation that would be obviously evident from the documentation, but I must be missing it.

Comment: Have you tried running the executable from command-line?? using appropriate command line parameters [http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html] .

Comment: are you capable of running an empty testcase ?
did you remember to add linkage info in your makefile? I have following in my Makefile : -lboost_system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that you have linkage info in your makefile; example :

```
-lboost_system -lboost_log -lboost_signals -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_regex
```

of course only add the boost which is needed for your specific testcase suite

Then in your test suite file have following:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE YourTestSuiteName                  
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK                            
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>      
#include <boost/test/results_reporter.hpp>             
#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN 

#ifndef NOTESTRESULTFILE                                                           
#ifdef BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN                                                        
std::ofstream out;                                                                 

struct ReportRedirector                                                            
{                                                                                  
    ReportRedirector()                                                             
    {                                                                              
        out.open("test_results.xml");                                              
        assert( out.is_open() );                                                   
        boost::unit_test::results_reporter::set_stream(out);                       
    }                                                                              
};                                                                                 

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(ReportRedirector)                                             
#endif                                                                             
#endif   

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE (YourTestSuiteName)            
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END( )                                            

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(YourTestCaseName)                                
{                                                                             
   cout<<"BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( YourTestCaseName )\n{"<<endl;         

   BOOST_CHECK(false == true);  //TODO: testcase not finished  

   cout<<"}"<<endl;                  
}
```

This setup works fine for me, but I am sure you can setup boost unit tests suites in a different way

Comment: Perhaps what you are missing is the statement : 
`#define BOOST_AUTO_TEST_MAIN`

Comment: Sending output to `std::cout` ends up going to the file automatically? The output isn't in `xml` format.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked the question, and I can't really try this now. However, it does have quite a bit of detail and looks like it would be correct, so I'm accepting this answer. If someone comes by and reads this and disagrees, please let me know.

Comment: @Steve, I normally use output file like this and then I run a xlstproc script sorting and giving me a nice final output, and yes not all is in xml format, so perhaps it should have a different name - well spottet :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

rather than

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

main is defined in the test/unit_test.hpp file.  "included" is an implementation detail.

Comment: I use bottom one without issues

Comment: You can use the bottom one but you aren't supposed to because the boost folks reserve the right to change things at that level without notice and your code might break the next time you upgraded to a new version of boost.  If you use the first version of the code your code will continue to work "forever" [barring major rewrites of boost which are extremely unlikely.]